# Bootstrap Multipage Form is Broken

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I am attempting to accomplish is a multi-page form which will be used for registration to my site.  Somehow or another, I have broken the form and do not know why it is not working.  Please help.
Here is the code:

```
    <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
      <h1>Register:</h1>
      <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
      <div class="tab">Name:
        <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Middle name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="mname"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Contact Info:
        <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Confirm E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>  
        <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Address:
        <p><input placeholder="Address1" oninput="this.className = ''" name="address1"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Address2" oninput="this.className = ''" name="address2"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="City" oninput="this.className = ''" name="city"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="State" oninput="this.className = ''" name="state"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Zip Code" oninput="this.className = ''" name="zipcode"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Country" oninput="this.className = ''" name="country"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Login Info:
        <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
      </div>
      <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:right;">
          <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
      <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how I broke the form.  I pasted the  into the  instead of being after the .  I have been working on this for days.  I guess I am just tired.  Thanks to everyone who looked at this.